# How to define a module in the browser under a namespace and in Node.js without a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns, module, global-variables

I have seen [this article](http://www.matteoagosti.com/blog/2013/02/24/writing-javascript-modules-for-both-browser-and-node/) and I know how to make a module for both the browser and Node. However, if it's been loaded in the browser, I want to save it under my namespace so that I don't pollute the global scope. The following works fine, but I leave the global `Validator` behind:

```js
var Validator = (function() {
  var exports = {};

  exports.foo = function () {
    console.log("foo");
  };

  return exports;
})();

if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
  module.exports = Validator;
} else {
  Namespace = {}; // this has been previously defined in another file
  Namespace.Validator = Validator;
}

Namespace.Validator.foo(); // good
Validator.foo(); // bad
```

---

I tried:

```js
(
  (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports)
    ? module.exports
    : Namespace.Validator
) = (function() {
  // ...
  return {};
})();
```

But it throws:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

---

I tried:

```js
Namespace = {}; // again, this is defined in my code somewhere else

(function(module) {
  module.foo = function () {
    console.log("bar");
  };
})(
  (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports)
    ? module.exports
    : Namespace.Validator
);
```

But `Namespace.Validator` is `undefined`.

I could add `Namespace.Validator = {}` at the top, but then in Node.js, I would have to create `Namespace`.

### Question

Is there a way I could properly do this without a global variable:

```
// In the browser:
Namespace.MyModule = {...};

// In Node.js:
module.exports = {...};
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up throwing everything in an IIFE:

```js
Namespace = {}; // from another file

(function() {
  var MyModule = (function() {
    return {
      foo: function() {
        console.log("bar");
      }
    };
  })();

  if (typeof module !== "undefined" && module.exports) {
    module.exports = MyModule;
  } else if (typeof Namespace !== "undefined") {
    Namespace.MyModule = MyModule;
  }
})();

console.log(Namespace.MyModule);
```

### If there is another way to do this, please, add it as an answer.